# Dynamic programming approach to from number list (use pseudo code)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

**STATE the running time of the methods. Polynomial time algorithms are expected.**

A club wants to organize a party for the students. However, only part of the students can attend
the party. The candidates are choosing by pairs with the following requirements: assume the
students are lined-up, each student is given a lucky number, and some students may have the
same lucky numbers. The club requires that only students who have the same luck numbers may
be paired-up and join in the party while all the students locate within a chosen pair will lose the
opportunity.
We have helped the club to formulate the problem formally.
Given a sequence of positive integers (represent the lucky numbers) `A = (a1, a2, ... an)`, a pair `(ai, aj)` is defined as a dancing pair if `ai=aj`, and `i<j`. A dancing pair list L={(1, 1),… (, ) }
is good if and only if for any two pairs (, ), (, ) of L, either `jx<iy` or `jy<ix` for `1 ≤ ,  ≤` .

For example, if A={1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5}, some good dancing lists might be:

{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)} (locations in A={**1**, 3, 4, **1**, **2**, 3, **2**, 4, **3**, 5, **3**, 4, 5})

{(1, 1), (3, 3) (5, 5)} (locations in A={**1**, 3, 4, **1**, 2, **3**, 2, 4, **3**, **5**, 3, 4, **5**})

a) Given a sequence of positive integers A, design a polynomial time algorithm to find a
good dancing pair list with maximum number of dancing pairs.

b) Assume the weight of the dancing pair `(ai, aj)` is `ai+aj`. The total weight of a good dancing
list is the sum of all the weights of the dancing pairs in the list. Design a polynomial time
algorithm to find a good dancing pair list with maximum total weight.

for part a,
if i write like this

```
foreach list L
    foreach item I in list L
        foreach list L2 such that L2 != L  
            for each item I2 in L2
                if I == I2
                    return new 3-tuple(L, L2, I) //
```

how to continue?

Comment: So the output of the algorithm would be a list of dancing pairs? I have some trouble understanding the definition of the dancing pairs. Could you give a more detailed example?

Comment: Fix the formatting please -- the part after "if ai=aj" has been cut off.

Comment: just output something like:
{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)}
{(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4)}

and those list are with maximum  number of dancing list in part (a)
and maximum total weight in part (b).